# Add association in entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In a legacy product I have the following two tables:

```
Create Table City (
    Id int identity not null,
    Gid uniqueidentifier not null,
    Name varchar(25) not null,
    constraint PK_City Primary Key(Id)
    )   
Create Table CityExtra(
    Gid uniqueidentifier not null,
    CityGid  uniqueidentifier not null,
    ExtraName varchar(25) not null,
    constraint PK_CityExtra Primary Key(Gid)
    )
```

In the EF editor I would like to create a one-one relation between these two entities.
Creating the association is not a problem, but how do I create the association mappings between City.Gid and CityExtra.CityGid (City.Gid is not a key)?
Or is this not possible?

Comment: EF doesn't support 1:1 relationships that aren't on the PK's.. Are you sure you want a 1:1?  You could do a 1:many where CityExtra could potentially have many Citys, but then in your business logic never actually have multiple cities.